# Renewed RootCA doesn't verify child certs

Tags: certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates, client-certificate

So i have a self signed rootCA which is expiring soon, so i created a new csr with updated info about the cert and company but im still using the same private key.

I create the new rootCA and install it on my windows machine but for some reason all the other child certs that were signed by the prev/expired cert are not being verified by the new rootCA. is there any way to get around this issue? i dont want to have to re-create all the other child certs for this to work, there has to be a way right?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the new CA have the exact same Subject (not just values but also the data types), and the exact same subjectKeyIdentifier?

Comment: well no the values are a bit different because some things have changed, is that the cause of the issue?

Comment: Yes – that means it's not the same CA anymore.